# Wordpress site using unknown overriding css

Tags: css

I have an issue I can't solve. When my website loads it seems to be grabbing an old version of our customized CSS and using that to override all our new CSS. But that old version no longer exists. I have no idea where it's coming from.

If you look at our page source here: [view-source:http://www.universaltheosophy.com/](http://view-source:http://www.universaltheosophy.com/) then scroll down and you'll see a bunch of css code, some of which I have no idea where it's coming from. After this:

```
/*----------------------------------
*          end review
----------------------------------*/
```

You'll see stuff like this:

```
#navigation .inner {
width: 1250px !important;
}
```

I have no idea how to find out where this code is coming from. It's not in any of the CSS files under our theme's directory. I also tried turning off and disabling "wp supercache" after deleting the whole cache, thinking maybe the css was cached somewhere, but that did nothing. I've done a "string search" through the whole wordpress directory and can't find this css code anywhere!

The thing is, this css code *was* part of an old version of our customized CSS. We have a file called "custom-overrides-2.css" that is added to our theme's css files, which provides certain overrides. There was a previous version "custom-overrides-1.css", which I think contained the above css, but it's long since been deleted.

How can I find out where this code is coming from, and how do I get rid of it? It's completely f*ing up our mobile display, since our mobile "responsive.css" is being overridden by it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common problem when themes let you add some "free style" css as part of its options, try to look for such an option.

In general never use this kinds of options if you can create a child theme and directly modify its css.

Answer (score 0):

As I seen you used Goodnews WordPress theme.. And its comes with Advance Theme Options panel have you check the Custom CSS under the Theme Options?

OR

You can overwrite this by adding your own styles using "!important" in Custom CSS at end of the line.